# PHP Cache Headers with CDN

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, cache-control

I am trying the php header() function to set caching headers to my page. I have a CDN that caches the http requests. What I am trying to achieve here is that the CDN should cache my page for 2 days, and the browser should check for new version to the CDN every 5 minutes.

```
Cache-Control: max-age=300, s-maxage=172800, public
```

Does this avoe cache header work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does this avoe cache header work?

Why don't you know from your traffic?

[Manual](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt):

```
s-maxage
   If a response includes an s-maxage directive, then for a shared
   cache (but not for a private cache), the maximum age specified by
   this directive overrides the maximum age specified by either the
   max-age directive or the Expires header.
```

Yes, it should work - but makes no sense to use a shorter expiry time on the client than on an intermediate proxy (unless the client is likely to move between different CDN zones and the content is CDN zone specific).

Comment: The reason is that I can purge the cache on CDN whenever I want, but can't touch the cache on the user's browser. Suppose, If I change my content within 6 hours of adding it, I can purge the CDN copy, and the user would still see new copy.

Comment: ...and what if the content is accessed via a secondary proxy which you can't control?

Answer (score 0):

The expires header is the one you are looking for, it tells all caches how long the associated representation is fresh for. After that time, caches will always check back with the origin server to see if a document is changed.

Also, if your pages are not password protected, use `must-revalidate`.

You would have a method at the CDN to set your TTL to 2 days

Comment: Mybe you should RTFM too: "The s-maxage directive also implies the semantics of the proxy-revalidate directive"